# Audio player in Android

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-mediaplayer, android-audiomanager, android-notification-bar

I designed an app which plays 12 different audio files based on the item selected in the list view from server. When the audio is playing and I hit home button in the emulator I can see the notification in notification bar but when I click it the audio player is restarting but the previous audio is still playing.

I need the audio player to show me the present state  of the audio player when the notification icon is clicked.

Comment: You mention "The present state of the audio player" needs to be shown? What does this mean. Could you provide some code

Comment: I mean "The audio is already playing and the screen needs to show the state of the progress bar where it is present after I pressed the home button and came back to the app through notification icon."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your activity is brought to the foreground you can override using the onResume.

I'm assuming your using a ProgressBar to display progress. So you can set the progress bar to the current position by using the getCurrentPosition method of media player. (do this in onResume)

That should set it to proper position. Then restart any CountDown or operation to update ProgressBar and it should work